# My jQuery DataTable checkbox is not working, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to implement checkbox to submit as form but I realized it will not work this way. What is the correct way to implement this? I read some example here but couldn't understand.

```
<form method="post" name="search_form" action="<?php echo $linksearch; ?>">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="search_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Process1</th>
<th>Process2</th>
<th>Process3</th>
<th>Process4</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$sql = "select * from activity_temp";
$result=tep_db_query($sql);
$sc=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$row['p1']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['p2']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['p3']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['p4']."</td>";
   echo "<td class=\"center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"search_cb[".$row['temp_id']."]\" value=\"on\"></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
$sc++;
}
?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr><td colspan="5" align="right">
<input id="search_form_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="submit" />
</td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</form>
```

Do I do this?

```
$('#search_table').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
       "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [4]
    }],
   "aoColumns": [
    { "mDataProp": "checkBox" }],
           "aaData": [{
        "checkBox": "<input type="checkbox" name="search_cb" value="on" />"
    }]         
});
```

Comment: If your JavaScript code really looks like that, at least one reason it doesn't work is the inconsistent use of quotation marks in the `checkBox` property. Either escape the double quotes or use single quotes inside the double-quoted value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form').submit( function() {
    var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
    alert( "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+sData );
    return false;
} );
```

Source: http://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html